# XSL How to render html within element with no CDATA tag

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm having trouble rendering html tag from my xml. It comes out as text.

XML:

```
 <object>
  <output_pid>uk-ac-man-scw:16844</output_pid>
  <output_title>Graphene: exploring carbon flatland</output_title>
  <output_type>Journal article</output_type>
  <output_state>open</output_state>
  <output_createddate>2009-09-25T13:54:34.538Z</output_createddate>
  <output_issueddate>2007</output_issueddate>
  <output_year>2007</output_year>
  <output_citation>A.K. Geim, A.H. MacDonald. (2007). Graphene: exploring carbon flatland. <em>Physics Today</em>, 60(8), 35-41.  eScholarID:<a class="escholarid"
        href="http://www.manchester.ac.uk/escholar/uk-ac-man-scw:16844">16844</a> | DOI:<a class="doi" href="http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2774096">10.1063/1.2774096</a>
  </output_citation>
  <output_journal>Physics Today</output_journal>
```

XSL (1.0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="output_citation">
                        <xsl:sort select="//output_createddate"  data-type="text" order="descending"/> 

                        <li>                                
                            <xsl:value-of select="."  />                                   
                           </li>

                    </xsl:for-each>
```

Output comes out as raw tags and not html formatting:

```
<li>T. C. Lovejoy, Q. M. Ramasse, M. Falke, A. Kaeppel, R. Terborg, R. Zan, N. Dellby and O. L. Krivanek. (2012). Single atom
     identification by energy dispersive x-ray spectroscopy. Applied Physics Letters, 100(15), 154101.  eScholarID:213891 | DOI:10.1063/1.3701598

  </li>
```

This is the output that I want
(Basically everything within the output_citation tag  (not the output_citation tag) with html tags mainatind but excluding the ):

```
  <li>
     T. C. Lovejoy, Q. M. Ramasse, M. Falke, A. Kaeppel, R. Terborg, R. Zan, N. Dellby and O. L. Krivanek. (2012). Single atom
        identification by energy dispersive x-ray spectroscopy. <em>Applied Physics Letters</em>, 100(15), 154101.  eScholarID:<a class="escholarid" href="http://www.manchester.ac.uk/escholar/uk-ac-man-scw:213891">213891</a> | DOI:<a class="doi" href="http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3701598">10.1063/1.3701598</a>               

  </li>
```

Also, disable-output-escaping has no effect as there are no CDATA wrapping.

Many thanks

Comment: I think you need to call `<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="."  />` and you need an xsl copy template for all html tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first step you could use `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="."  />` as that way you would copy all child nodes. I would however suggest to put an `<xsl:apply-templates/>` and then to make sure there are other templates like the identity transformation template for the elements you want to copy:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Depending on your needs that template might only list the elements you want to copy.

And based on your edit you want

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//output_citation"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="output_citation">
  <li>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
```

That way, together with first template in this answer, you should get the output you want.

Comment: It does output all elements but I want only one <output_citation>.
How do i get it to only ouput this element?
Thanks

Comment: Your code as shown so far suggests that you want to transform each `output_citation` into an `li` element and then want to output the contents of the `output_citation` inside the `li`. My suggestions would achieve that. You will need to edit your question showing the context, both for your XML input sample as well as for the XSLT and for the wanted result.

Comment: OK, i've edited the XML in my orig post.  Basically I want to transform the output_citation content into a li and exclude all other elemnts and the output_citation tag.  Many thanks

Comment: @kevmull So what is the **exact** output that you want? Please edit your question and clarify this point.

Comment: @kevmull And that is the output you will get if you follow the instructions given by this answer.  Read also the end of the second comment above.